# Move a Sftp User in a Subdirectory of his Jail

Tags: linux, security, ssh, system-administration, jail

I've a question concerning the Jail explained later:

- User to be jailed: `foo`
- Jail Directory: `/mnt/foo-jail`
- Home directory of foo: `/mnt/foo-jail/foo-home`

Everything is ok. Jail is up and the user is connecting correctly.

- The problem is: **"foo" has not write-permission on his Jail** directory, but he has write-permission on his Home directory. When he connects to my server, he is redirected to /mnt/foo-jail (his Jail) and not in his Home (/mnt/foo-jail/foo-home) where he can write;

How can I resolv this problem? He cannot make CHDIR to move among folders, but He must be **redirected to his own Home Dir**.

Thank you very very much for your help !!!

### Edit: Resolved

I'll write the interesting part of ssh configuration file **sshd_config**, hoping it could be useful for someone.

`Match user foo
    ChrootDirectory /mnt/foo-jail/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    AuthorizedKeysFile /mnt/foo-jail/%h/.ssh/authorized_keys
    X11Forwarding no`

In the file **/etc/passwd**, foo appears like:

`foo:x:1001:1001:Foo User,,,:/foo-home:/bin/bash`

Pay attention to the home, which is **/foo-home** and not /foo-home/, otherwise ssh could not intercept the correct path of the key.

Comment: This is more a topic for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
ChrootDirectory %h
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in the `Match Group` section. `%h` is replaced by the home directory of the connecting user.

Answer (score 0):

ChrootDirectory /upload/%u

ForceCommand internal-sftp -d data

This will put the sftp in /upload/UserXX/data directory.  The data directory is owned and read/writable by the UserXX